# Resize Window ad keep divs on same place

Tags: html, css

Well.. my english is not good, so i draw what i want..

FULL PAGE: http://d-3.me/full.jpg

The green container it's my content wrap. The Black and Red Squares, are some button's to access another pages.

So when i resize the page, i want to keep theses button's like this another image:

1024px Window Views: http://d-3.me/1024.jpg

this is my initial HTML :

```
<div id="wrap_home_bts">
    <div class="bt_woman"></div>
    <div class="bt_man"></div>
</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
#wrap_home_bts{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

    .bt_woman{
        width:880px;
        height:389px;
        background:#FFCC00;

        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        bottom:245px;

    }

    .bt_man{
        width:733px;
        height:168px;
        background:#CC00FF;

        position:absolute;
        right:0;
        bottom:74px;

    }
```

but this way, the "button's" accompanies the resized window.

I clear?

Comment: Take a look at media queries: css-tricks.com/css-media-queries

Comment: Have you tried to set the width of bt_woman and bt_man in % instead of in px?

Comment: @WillemVanBockstal Setting width in % doesn't bring any fruit.

Comment: @RehanMehdi Do you have a jsfiddle of your specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of positioning your blocks using left and right 0px, position them to 50%, and then align them the way you want using a negative margin. This should work, although you'll have to adjust the margins to fit exactly like you want:

```
#wrap_home_bts{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

.bt_woman{
    width:880px;
    height:389px;
    background:#FFCC00;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -650px;
    bottom:245px;

}

.bt_man{
    width:733px;
    height:168px;
    background:#CC00FF;

    position:absolute;
    display: block;
    left:50%;
    margin-right: -650px;
    bottom:74px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E4mmz/

Answer (score 0):

.bt_woman and .bt_man are absolutely positioned in #wrap_home_bts which's width is set to 100%. That way #wrap_home_bts size will change with browser resizing and the position of .bt_woman and .bt_man will follow this element. Perhaps it will be better that  .bt_woman and .bt_man to be outside the #wrap_home_bts. Then you may set some width to the body element with javaScript, like the width of the screen. That way they will never change there position on resize.